# Range of IP pinging

Tags: python

Okay so, I want to be able to input a starting and ending IP and ping all the IP addresses inbetween them including the ones listed and then display their results into a .txt document. I can get it to work for a single IP, but I don't know how to make it so the user has to input 2 IP's and it successfully pings all the ones inbetween. Thanks. This is currently what I have but am having trouble.

```
def pingNetwork():


startingIP = raw_input("Enter starting IP address: ")
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + startingIP)
for ip in range(1, 100):

 if response == 0:
    with open('IP_LOG_TIMESTAMP.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(startingIP + ' is up!')
 else:
    with open('IP_LOG_TIMESTAMP.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(startingIP + ' is down!')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import struct
import socket

def findIPs(start, end):
    ipstruct = struct.Struct('>I')
    start, = ipstruct.unpack(socket.inet_aton(start))
    end, = ipstruct.unpack(socket.inet_aton(end))
    return [socket.inet_ntoa(ipstruct.pack(i)) for i in range(start, end+1)]

def pingNetwork(range_ips):
    for ip in range_ips:
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ip)
        if response == 0:
            with open('IP_LOG_TIMESTAMP.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write(ip+ ' is up!')
        else:
            with open('IP_LOG_TIMESTAMP.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write(ip+ ' is down!')

ips = findIPs('111.111.111.0', '111.111.111.3')
pingNetwork(ips)
```